# Only a view filters in exposed filter block

Tags: views

I have a view with 7 exposed filters in an exposed filters block.

But I only want to have 2 filters in the exposed form block. All 7 filters I want to have on the views page.

Is there another solution then display: none?

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the view for your second use case and only make the 2 needed filters exposed and expose that as a block.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new page display, this will copy all the fields and filters from the 'master' display.
2. Click on the filter you want to remove from the block display.
3. Select "This block (override)" from the top.
4. Click remove.

Refer the screenshot:

[image: snap]

**NOTE:** I took the snapshot for the filter "This page (override)". In your case please make sure you select "This block (override) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But what I forgot to write:

When applying the exposed filter I redirect to the views page. Means: for example the filter is placed on frontpage and when applying it the user will be redirected to the path of the view.

This is because there's no space for the view results.